# I keep on getting error in rc.local

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian, rc

I have the following script added to my rc.local file

```
#wait until the internet connection is ready
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null
while [ $? -ne 0 ]; do
        printf "Waiting for internet connection"
        sleep  10;
        wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null;

done
```

If I am connected to internet everything just works fine  but if I am offline I get error

```
[FAIL] startpar: service(s) returned failure: rc.local ... failed!
```

What is wrong here and how could I fix it, I want rc.local to wait for internet connection before it continues to another script

Comment: Probably won't fix your issue but there's no need to test the exit code separately, you can do `while ! wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null; do`

Comment: Thanks, It works now :) Can you explain me why it might have failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it appears to have solved your problem, this is how I would suggest writing your code:

```
while ! wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 -O - http://google.com > /dev/null; do
    echo 'Waiting for internet connection'
    sleep 10
done
```

Remember that `[` is not syntax, it is a command whose exit status determines whether your `while` loop continues or not. You should just test the exit status of the command you are trying to run directly.

As for *why* this has solved your problem, to be honest I'm not sure. The error message that you have shown isn't really specific enough to indicate where the problem lies and I can't see anything actually wrong with what you did before. Perhaps you should try adding `set -xv` to your `rc.local` file to enable debugging.